# How do I run a slideshow from a extern .js archive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem is this: I make a slideshow, when I put the css and the javascript code inside the same page, it "works"(because it goes transparent in like a half second), but I don't like to do it like that. I see it more orderly when it's separated(one archive for each one), but when I put it on an extern .js file... it does not run the images, the css is fine, it works, but the javascript, just wont... HELP?

Here the code:

```js
/*JavaScript*/

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/*CSS*/

* {box-sizing:border-box}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

.mySlides {
    display: none;
}

* {box-sizing:border-box}
body {font-family: Verdana,sans-serif;margin:0}
.mySlides {display:none}

/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

/* On smaller screens, decrease text size */
@media only screen and (max-width: 300px) {
  .prev, .next,.text {font-size: 11px}
}
```

```html
<!--HTML-->

<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Java y CSS/ElagarWebJS.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="Multimedia/Bloc o Note.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Cualquiera de estos dos es buena alternativa, pero el obvio ganador es Notepad++ con sus distintos leguajes y su autocompletación</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="Multimedia/IE o CH.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Aunque ambos funcionan bien, Chrome gana este round pues esta a la vanguardia con los scripts, cookies, y bueno... es Google</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="Multimedia/Ganas.png" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Puede llegar a ser muy, Muy, MUY estresante asi que cuidado... Diviertete</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are either not placing the files in the right order or you are not calling them properly.

I will suggest to use OwlCarousel, it's responsive, easy to use and implement.

It can save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are right when you say it is better to have an extern file than the code inside the "same page".
Meaning that you need to say to your code... "go there an pick that code for me "

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css">
```

that should be on the header.

Inside the body, really before you close it

```
<body> ...


...

<script src="myscripts.js"></script>

</body>
```

there is alot of discussion where to call your javascript file, but onside body or header both will work.

Just be sure you are giving it the right path and name, meaning

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Java y CSS/ElagarWebJS.js"></script>
```

would mean, inside the folder you are at, there exist another folder called "Java y CSS" and then inside should be the file "ElagarWebJS.js".

Is it the full code? where do you have your body? how does even your css work since I don't see you calling it.

Anyway, following what i wrote you, will solve it for you i hope :)